# Duplicate calling inet_ntop() function

Tags: c, redundancy, getaddrinfo, inet-ntop

Please help me! I need to translate (or convert) domain names (for example google.com) to IP address. For that purpose I have found code on interet, which work perfectly, but I don't understand, why there is called function inet_ntop() two times. Please help me. Here is code:

```
/* 
 * getaddrinfo.c - Simple example of using getaddrinfo(3) function.
 * 
 * Michal Ludvig <michal@logix.cz> (c) 2002, 2003
 * http://www.logix.cz/michal/devel/
 *
 * License: public domain.
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int
lookup_host (const char *host)
{
  struct addrinfo hints, *res;
  int errcode;
  char addrstr[100];
  void *ptr;

  memset (&hints, 0, sizeof (hints));
  hints.ai_family = PF_UNSPEC;
  hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
  hints.ai_flags |= AI_CANONNAME;

  errcode = getaddrinfo (host, NULL, &hints, &res);
  if (errcode != 0)
    {
      perror ("getaddrinfo");
      return -1;
    }

  printf ("Host: %s\n", host);
  while (res)
    {
      inet_ntop (res->ai_family, res->ai_addr->sa_data, addrstr, 100);

      switch (res->ai_family)
        {
        case AF_INET:
          ptr = &((struct sockaddr_in *) res->ai_addr)->sin_addr;
          break;
        case AF_INET6:
          ptr = &((struct sockaddr_in6 *) res->ai_addr)->sin6_addr;
          break;
        }
      inet_ntop (res->ai_family, ptr, addrstr, 100);
      printf ("IPv%d address: %s (%s)\n", res->ai_family == PF_INET6 ? 6 : 4,
              addrstr, res->ai_canonname);
      res = res->ai_next;
    }

  return 0;
}

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  if (argc < 2)
    exit (1);
  return lookup_host (argv[1]);
}
```

My question is - why there is function inet_ntop() used twice? I thought, that the first calling give you IP address...but why you need the second calling?
Thanks!

Comment: I would avoid `inet_ntop()` and call `getnameinfo(res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen, addrstr, sizeof(addrstr), NULL, 0, NI_NUMERICHOST)`. It avoids the need for the `switch`-statement.

Answer (score 1):

The first call to `inet_ntop` isn't doing anything useful here.  What it writes to `addrstr` is overwritten on the following call.

The author either didn't understand why they were calling it twice or left in test code they shouldn't have.